# Unregister receiver in Manifest xml file

Tags: android

When I create and register my receiver like this in my Manifest.xml,

Do I need to do anything to unregister?

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.mycompanh.MyStartReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if declaring in manifest you dont need to do anything